# PHP file stops working with no changes made to it

Tags: php, linux, permissions, raspberry-pi, stripe-payments

I am trying to get a website to work, but cannot figure out how to edit the server PHP file without the website crashing. I am not getting many hits on google looking for this issue.

I am attempting to build a "stripe checkout" page, where you can put a hold on a card. I did not write any of this code, but got it on github.

https://github.com/stripe-samples/placing-a-hold

The index.php file is what I am trying to edit, but this is where I am having trouble:

https://github.com/stripe-samples/placing-a-hold/tree/master/using-webhooks/server/php

If I download the github link and open the php file through my browser, I get a checkout page as expected. However, if I copy and paste the file on my desktop, open it, save it (no edits), close it, and re-upload it to the server, it gives me a white screen. If I re-upload the original php file it works again. I dont see how two identical php files can give me this result. I was thinking that saving the php file changes the permissions associated with the file? but I did a chmod 777 to the entire directory, and it still doesn't work.

I don't have much coding experience. I checked the server error it says:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unexpected data in output buffer. Maybe you have characters before an opening <?php tag? in /var/www/html/server/php/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php:625
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/server/php/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(333): Slim\App->finalize(Object(Slim\Http\Response))
> #1 /var/www/html/server/php/index.php(112): Slim\App->run()
> #2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/server/php/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php on line 625,

going into the App.php file around line 625 it has this:

```
protected function finalize(ResponseInterface $response)
{
    // stop PHP sending a Content-Type automatically
    ini_set('default_mimetype', '');

    $request = $this->container->get('request');
    if ($this->isEmptyResponse($response) && !$this->isHeadRequest($request)) {
        return $response->withoutHeader('Content-Type')->withoutHeader('Content-Length');
    }

    // Add Content-Length header if `addContentLengthHeader` setting is set
    if (isset($this->container->get('settings')['addContentLengthHeader']) &&
        $this->container->get('settings')['addContentLengthHeader'] == true) {
        if (ob_get_length() > 0) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("Unexpected data in output buffer. " .
                "Maybe you have characters before an opening <?php tag?");
        }
        $size = $response->getBody()->getSize();
        if ($size !== null && !$response->hasHeader('Content-Length')) {
            $response = $response->withHeader('Content-Length', (string) $size);
        }
    }

    // clear the body if this is a HEAD request
    if ($this->isHeadRequest($request)) {
        return $response->withBody(new Body(fopen('php://temp', 'r+')));
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Just a guess. Maybe the editor you're using is adding something by its own. Which one are you using? Maybe try using another one.

Comment: Thank you that ended up being the issue. I was opening the PHP file in notepad. For some reason that was corrupting it. I downloaded Atom and opened it through that, and it ended up working.